# NuxtJS Vue-i18n - "Cannot read property 'fallbackLocale' of undefined"

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-i18n

I want to use [vue-i18n](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/) in my nuxtjs app but I always get this error:

```
Cannot read property 'fallbackLocale' of undefined
```

I think it has something to do with my middleware:

```
//middleware/i18n.js
export default function ({ isHMR, app, store, route, params, error, redirect }) {
  const defaultLocale = app.i18n.fallbackLocale
  // If middleware is called from hot module replacement, ignore it
  if (isHMR) return
  const locale = route.query.lang || defaultLocale
  if (store.state.locales.indexOf(locale) === -1) {
    return error({ message: 'This page could not be found.', statusCode: 404 })
  }
  //Mutate the store's locale once we understand which locale is being requested prior to each page render
  store.commit('SET_LANG', locale)
  // Set locale from the query string '?lang='**''
  app.i18n.locale = store.state.locale  
}
```

But in *i18n.js* I clearly set `app.i18n.fallbackLocale`:

```
//plugins/i18n.js
export const i18n = ({ app, store }) => {
  // inject our i18n instance into the app root to be used in middleware
  // we assume a store/index.js file has been defined and the variable 'locale' defined on store, we'll go into this in detail in the next code snippet
  app.i18n = new VueI18n({ //construction a new VueI18n
    locale: store.state.locale,
    fallbackLocale: 'de',
    messages: {
      //'locales' directory contains all the translations in the form of json files
      'en': require('~/static/locales/en.json'), 
      'de': require('~/static/locales/de.json')
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`nuxt.config.js` Delete:

```
    {
      src: '@/plugins/i18n.js',
      ssr: false
    },
```

`nuxt.config.js` Usage:

```
    '@/plugins/i18n.js',
```